# CreateFileMapping returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to use CreateFileMapping for the first time and it is giving me this error when I use GetLastError():

```
ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE: The handle is invalid.
```

Here is my code:

```
    // create the name of our file-mapping object
    nTry++; // Ensures a unique string is used in case user closes and reopens
    wsprintfA(szName, FS6IPC_MSGNAME1 ":%X:%X", GetCurrentProcessId(), nTry);
    // stuff the name into a global atom
    m_atom = GlobalAddAtomA(szName);
    if (m_atom == 0)
   {    *pdwResult = ERR_ATOM;
        return FALSE;
    }

    // create the file-mapping object
    m_hMap = CreateFileMappingA(
                    (HANDLE)0xFFFFFFFF, // use system paging file
                    NULL,               // security
                    PAGE_READWRITE,     // protection
                    0, MAX_SIZE+256,       // size
                   szName);            //
```

EDIT:

The first issue was resolved, but now my program crashes somewhere else.

```
#define FS6IPC_MESSAGE_SUCCESS 1
#define FS6IPC_MESSAGE_FAILURE 0

// IPC message types
#define FS6IPC_READSTATEDATA_ID    1
#define FS6IPC_WRITESTATEDATA_ID   2

// read request structure
typedef struct tagFS6IPC_READSTATEDATA_HDR
{
  DWORD dwId;       // FS6IPC_READSTATEDATA_ID
  DWORD dwOffset;   // state table offset
  DWORD nBytes;     // number of bytes of state data to read
  void* pDest;      // destination buffer for data (client use only)
} FS6IPC_READSTATEDATA_HDR;

// write request structure
typedef struct tagFS6IPC_WRITESTATEDATA_HDR
{
  DWORD dwId;       // FS6IPC_WRITESTATEDATA_ID
  DWORD dwOffset;   // state table offset
  DWORD nBytes;     // number of bytes of state data to write
} FS6IPC_WRITESTATEDATA_HDR;
```

---

```
while (*pdw)
{   switch (*pdw)
    {   case FS6IPC_READSTATEDATA_ID:
            pHdrR = (FS6IPC_READSTATEDATA_HDR *) pdw;
            m_pNext += sizeof(FS6IPC_READSTATEDATA_HDR);
            if (pHdrR->pDest && pHdrR->nBytes)
                CopyMemory(pHdrR->pDest, m_pNext, pHdrR->nBytes);
            m_pNext += pHdrR->nBytes; // Debugger says the issue is here
            break;

        case FS6IPC_WRITESTATEDATA_ID:
            // This is a write, so there's no returned data to store
            pHdrW = (FS6IPC_WRITESTATEDATA_HDR *) pdw;
            m_pNext += sizeof(FS6IPC_WRITESTATEDATA_HDR) + pHdrW->nBytes;
            break;

        default:
            // Error! So terminate the scan
            *pdw = 0;
            break;
    }

    pdw = (DWORD *) m_pNext;
}
```

Comment: To use the system paging file, the first argument should be INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That crashes my application.

Comment: Does it crash during the call to CreateFileMapping or afterwards?  What compiler are you using?  Are you building a 32-bit or a 64-bit application?

Comment: @HarryJohnston It crashes at this line: `m_pNext += pHdrR->nBytes;`. I put the full code into the main question window.

Comment: If another process (or thread) is modifying the shared memory while your code is working on it, the problem is probably that you're not synchronizing access to the memory properly.  If not, I don't see quite how it could fail on that particular line, but it seems likely that the problem is due to bad data in the memory buffer, and you'll need to step through the loop in question one line at a time watching for when it goes wrong.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Does this help any? This is the error that is thrown when I debug.

f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\string\amd64\memcpy.asm:254: error: Exception at 0x7fef122ab86, code: 0xc0000005: write access violation at: 0x1, flags=0x0 (first chance)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57724/discussion-between-chrisrockgm-and-harry-johnston).

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you're running on a 64-bit system, on which HANDLEs are 64 bits.  The OS is quite right—the handle value `0x00000000FFFFFFFF` is an invalid handle value for your process.

What exactly are you trying to do?  If you want to create a file mapping backed by an actual file, pass in the handle for that file.  If you want to a create a file mapping backed by the paging file instead, pass in `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.  `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` happens to be `(HANDLE)-1`, which is `0xFFFFFFFF` on 32-bit systems but `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` on 64-bit systems, but that doesn't really matter since you should just use the symbolic value `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` in any case.

If your application is crashing when you pass in `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, it's not because the call to `CreateFileMapping` is failing, it's for some other reason, and you should debug that.

Comment: I got this from my Qt debugger: Stopped in thread 0 by: Exception at 0x7feeaf1ab86, code: 0xc0000005: write access violation at: 0x1, flags=0x

Answer (score 0):

I get `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` from `CreateFileMappingA(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, ...)` when I already created a mutex using `CreateMutexA` using the same name. It seems that Windows requires unique naming across all named object types.

> If lpName matches the name of an existing event, semaphore, mutex, waitable timer, or job object, the function fails, and the GetLastError function returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. This occurs because these objects share the same namespace.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga